# Sitecore HTML Rendered as Plain Text

Tags: sitecore-client

I have a field "textContent" in `en` version which is of type Rich Text in sitecore 9

The content will be rendered to the site using the following code,

```
  @Html.Sitecore().Field(Model.textContent)
```

When the above rendering is edited through experience editor and saved, the html code is rendered as plain text in web page, not as a web page content.

Like

```
lt;a href="http://www.example.com" &amp;gt; Click Here &amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;
```

It should be

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Click Here </a>
```

In model, the data is pulled directly,

```
public string textContent
{
    get { return Constant.dataContentSpecific.TextContent; }
}
```

and in Constant file ,

```
public struct dataContentSpecific
{
    public static readonly string TextContent= "Text Content";
}
```

Comment: How this field looks in Rich Text editor (html)? As usual 
html "<а ... >" or encoded "lg; a ... "?

Comment: In editor, in normal view it is coming as <a href="....>

Comment: From showconfig, do you have Rich Text in the setting `HtmlEncodedFieldTypes`?

Comment: And if you use the field name directly in the code, does it work: @Html.Sitecore().Field(“Text Content”)

Comment: `<setting name="Rendering.HtmlEncodedFieldTypes" value="text|single-line text"/>`
It is there and yes, When I give directly the value in code also, it works like same way.

Comment: Is it some custom rich text field type maybe? Can you try `FieldRenderer.Render(item, "Text Content")` and check the result?

Comment: Since you are using your own Model, I think you need to use a HtmlString instead of String